# Search a string in an allocated array(c)

Tags: c

I want to find a string in an array stored in a pointer.I already tried this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
int n,i;
char (*ptr)[50];
char search[50];
printf("How many students?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Enter the name of student:\n");
    scanf("%49s", ptr[i]);
}
printf("Enter a name to search:\n");
scanf("%49s",search);
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf(strcmp(ptr[i],search));

}
}
```

But I see this error:

> [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: What do you want to print exactly?

Comment: `strcmp()` returns an integer — you'd need to print using an integer format.

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer to an array of 50 characters. It is not initialized, and it doe not point to sufficient memory required to read students names.

Comment: @medalib I want to print that is the string exists in the array or not.
Sorry, I didn't show it in the code.
I just want to find the string in the array.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen with the number of students is greater than 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `strcmp` returns `integer` not address(see https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). Replace `printf(strcmp(ptr[i],search));` 
should be
`printf("%d\n",strcmp(ptr[i],search));`

Secondly,  `char (*ptr)[50];` is pointer to an array, where its pointing ? Its unnecessary, better you can take array of pointer `char *ptr[50];`

```
char *ptr[50];/* array of 50 char ptr */
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      ptr[i] = malloc(size); /* allocate memory for each char buf, define size */
      printf("Enter the name of student:\n");
      scanf("%49s", ptr[i]);
}
```

And

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
     //printf("%d\n",strcmp(ptr[i],search));
     if(strcmp(ptr[i],search) == 0) {
       printf("%s exists \n",search);
     }
}
```

Also once job is done don't forget to `free` the dynamically allocated memory for each array of char pointer by calling `free()`. Something like this

```
for(int i =0 ;i < n;i++) {
   free(ptr[i]);
}
```

Comment: remember to free